# prove the recurrence sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Consider the sequene $\{a_n\}$: $a_1>0$ and $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=\frac{2n}{2n+a_n}$ for $n=2,3,\cdots$. Prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent.

To prove $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, we have to to  show it is monotone and bounded. But I'm unable to show it. How can I do it? Does there any ther simplest way to show the convergence ?

Since $a_1>0$, from the recurrance relation, it is easily seen that $a_n>0$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$.

Now, $a_n-a_{n+1}=\frac{(a_n+n)^2-n(n+2)}{2n}$ from this I can nt say anything about the sign , so that it proves increasing/decreasing!

Comment: Can you get an upper bound for the right-hand side of the recurrence using your observation $a_n >0$?

Comment: @Gary Yes. Rough upper bound is clearly $1$.

Comment: So $0 < a_n  < 1$ for all $n$. Can you squeeze $a_{n+1}$ using this fact and the recurrence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that
$$\alpha_{n+1}=\frac{2n}{2n+\alpha_n}\leq 1$$
for all $n$. This shows that $(\alpha_n)$ is bounded. Hence, $\alpha_n/2n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$. Now,
\begin{align}
\alpha_{n+1}&=\frac{2n}{2n+\alpha_n}\\
&=\frac{2n}{2n(1+\frac{\alpha_n}{2n})}\\
&=\biggl(1+\frac{\alpha_n}{2n}\biggr)^{-1}\to 1
\end{align}
since $\alpha_n/2n\to 0$.

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Comment: Excellent!.....